# expect: parsing a variable

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

There are many questions on regular expressions in expect but I have not found my answer.  I am new to expect but not regular expressions.  I have a variable in an expect script with this text:

```
IP Address Source       : Static Address
IP Address              : 1.2.3.4
Subnet Mask             : 255.255.255.0
```

I would like to parse out the values on the right side of the colons.  I have tried various versions of the following but I don't get a match.

```
if { [regexp -linestop "IP Address\s*:\s*(.+)" $network ignore ip] } {
   puts "IP: ($ip)"
}
```

It seems that the \s is not recognized as whitespace in expect?  Also tried versions with [[:space:]].  I need to look for the whitespace to distinguish the second line from the first. This matches something (not what I want) but when I add the '\s' as above it doesn't match at all.

```
if { [regexp -linestop "IP Address(.+)" $network ignore ip] } {
   puts "IP: ($ip)"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While `\s` *is* recognised as whitespace by the RE engine, it's preferentially treated as a quoted `s` at the general language level; not what you want! It's better by far to put regular expressions in `{`braces`}` instead of `"`double quotes`"` as that inhibits these unwanted escapes (and others too).

```
if { [regexp -linestop {IP Address\s*:\s*(.+)} $network ignore ip] } {
   puts "IP: ($ip)"
}
```

The only time this causes real problems is when you want to keep part of a regular expression in a variable. That's a much less common situation than wanting the Tcl language parsing engine to stay out of your way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them all:

```
% set x {IP Address Source       : Static Address
IP Address              : 1.2.3.4
Subnet Mask             : 255.255.255.0}
% foreach {all match} [regexp -line -all -inline {: (.*)} $x] {
    lappend values $match
}
% set values
{Static Address} 1.2.3.4 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex,

```
:\s(.+)
```

It captures the group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bO4aX4/1)

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I am having a more basic problem where it seems the \s is not being interpreted as a general whitespace match in my script

Comment: it works fine here , https://regex101.com/r/bO4aX4/2. Not sure what is the problem

Comment: The problem is that the `\s` is being interpreted as an `s`…